# Chaining several function definitions using the comma operator

Tags: javascript, uglifyjs

I was taking a look at the source code of Uglify-js where I noticed something interesting. In `bin/uglifyjs` ([ref](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS/blob/master/bin/uglifyjs)) a couple of functions are defined like this:

```
//syntax A
var defsym = function(sym) {
  ...
},
defval = function(v) {
  ...
};
```

Considering that Uglify-js is written by professionals and is used in many products like JQuery, I don't understand why the code isn't written like this:

```
//syntax B
var defsym = function(sym) {
  ...
};
var defval = function(v) {
  ...
};
```

This will make it more clear that these are two local variables. Or how about this:

```
//syntax C
function defsym(sym) {
  ...
}
function defval(v) {
  ...
}
```

This one makes the `defsym` and `defval` functions be available through the entire scope of the mother function.

Why would they choose the first syntax? Why not the other syntaxes?

Comment: yeah, why downvote? If someone doesn't like the question or don't know the answer, just ignore it.

Comment: Just FYI, that's not actually the comma operator. It just happens that the `var` statement uses the same character to declare multiple variables.

Comment: Please visit here: http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/2/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why wouldn't they use `Syntax B`? Because it requires more characters.

Why wouldn't they use `Syntax C`? Because its meaning is not entirely the same. Function declarations are not exactly the same as function expressions.

---

Now I see that the assignments are taking place in a `try/catch`, which means that they are in a block.

It's invalid to declare functions in a block *(even though some implementations allow it)*.

```
 // Invalid
try {
    function defsym(sym) {
        // ...
    }
    // ...
} catch(e) {
    // ...
}
```

---

```
 // Valid
try {
    var defsym = function(sym) {
        // ... 
    },
    // ...
} catch(e) {
    // ...
}
```

So this explains why they didn't choose `Syntax C`.

Also, "strict mode" will absolutely prohibit such invalid declarations by throwing an error.

Comment: and why in that context the programmer would prefer function expressions over function declaration? (code: https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS/blob/master/bin/uglifyjs)

Comment: @AlexStack: Now that I see that the assignment is in a `try/catch` block, the reason is that it isn't valid to have a function declaration in a statement block. This requires a `var` statement. Now, the fact is that many browsers allow such function declarations to take place without throwing an error, but to make them function declarations as in `Syntax C`, it would technically be invalid code, and would likely throw an error in "strict mode".

Answer (score 4):

I think this is just a matter of style. The first two definitions are equivalent but the first one is shorter as you don't have to prefix each definition with a `var`.

Same goes with assigning other values than functions to vars. E.g.

```
var a = "a",
    b = "b";
```

is the same as

```
var a = "a";
var b = "b";
```

It really boils down to personal preference (I like the second style more).

Comment: I think as Teemu suggested, it might be to avoid side effects of "hoisting".

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple var declaration.

if this is valid:

```
var number1 = 1, number2 = 2;
```

this is also valid:

```
var func1 = function(){}, func2 = function(){};
```

The only difference is that the second example is storing functions instead of integers.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation but I know what the comma operator is. The question is about WHY the functions are defined like that instead of the [arguably] common ways to define it (the syntax B and syntax C).

Comment: Coding style. And just to point out, syntax C does not have a trailing `;`, and it is not the same as the syntax A and B, because these two can be overwritten.